# Como obter o valor de um campo de uma outra tabela com ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby

Olá, a questão é o seguinte: tenho classes que usam dados de outras classes, preciso que carreguem os valores cadastrados nessas outras classes, mostrar isso em uma página html. 
Esta é a estrutura de uma classe que recebe dados de outras classes.

```html
 field :name, type: String
 field :acronym, type: String
 field :popular_names, type: Array
 field :description, type: String
 field :free, type: Boolean
 field :applicants, type: Array
 field :estimated_time, type: Hash
 field :steps, type: Array
 field :permalink, type: String
 field :other_informations, type: String

 belongs_to :organ, class_name: "Admin::Organ"
 has_and_belongs_to_many :units, class_name: "Admin::Unit"
 has_and_belongs_to_many :audiences, class_name: "Admin::Audience"
 has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, class_name: "Admin::Category"

 before_save :touch_permalink

 search_in :name, :popular_names
```

e gostaria de que fosse mostrado em uma página html, sei que está salvando no banco, mas não estou conseguindo recuperar os dados dessas foreignkeys

Comment: Acho que você precisa detalhar mais sua situação...

Comment: só ir acessando pelos relacionamentos. <%= casa.comodo.cama.valor %>